# How do I find out the system temporary directory?

Tags: macos

I'm testing an app that uses the System temp Directory. Inside of the app, there is some call to a Cocoa function to query this. Is there a way for me to query for this directory name outside of having to write a Cocoa app of my own? Possibly a command that I can issue in Terminal?

Comment: I found this answer great plus it works on Linux platforms too (probably not a huge concern for you, I realise): http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84980/68885

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
env
```

Just type this command into Terminal.  With zero arguments it'll print the names and values of variables in the environment.

Alternative with a bit more typing:

```
echo $TMPDIR
```

Comment: Thanks. What a weird path - /var/folders/iz/izqn2b5MF-iz9oL0CURH1U+++TI/-Tmp-/

Comment: This is not a good answer, since this env variable points to different directory every time a different process is invoked. It is made to let each process freely write into a "temp" directory, without worrying that it might overwrite (or read by mistake) something another application wrote.

Answer (score 5):

OS X has Python pre-installed, though not necessarily a fresh Python; but this is not cutting-edge stuff.

So:

Open a terminal

```
cat > hack.py
import tempfile
print tempfile.gettempdir()
^D
python hack.py
```

[Credit to nosklo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847850/cross-platform-way-of-getting-temp-directory-in-python/847866#847866)